# Why am I getting a server error '/' application for watk web sites and sql server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I am using the WATK to learn development skills in `VS2010` and `Windows Azure`. The training lab I am currently working on is "Windows Azure Web Sites and Virtual Machines using `ASP.NET` and `SQL Server` (from folder ASPNETAzureWebSitesVMSQL). I have created my VM in Azure etc and I am using the "End" Visual Studio solution. Thus the only change I have made to the project is specifying the DNS URL, port number, username and password for the database. When I try to run the application locally (using VS 2010) I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

I do not know what the problem is. Any suggestions?